# Is there any method in the Konva.js that reacts to any changes in the shape's attributes?

Tags: konvajs

In the documentation, I found listeners *'dragmove'*, *'transform'* etc.
Is there some kind of universal listener for updating any attribute property?

Comment: You could make a proxy on the Shape.attrs list - some info about it in this [blog post](https://longviewcoder.com/2021/07/27/konva-synchronisation-across-canvases/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. At the current version, `konva@8.3.1` doesn't have one event for all changes.

There are only three methods how attributes can be changes:

1. Programmatically using attribute setters
2. Dragging
3. Transforming

For #2 and #3 you can use `dragmove` and `transform` events.

For the first case, it is your code, so you know attributes are changed. You can call any custom code after a setter function.

Also, there are change events for every attribute: `xChange`, `yChange`, `fillChange`, etc. If you know a list of expected changes, you can use these events.

```js
shape.on('scaleXChange strokeChange', () => {
  console.log('something changed');
});
```